# YUI3 DataSourceXMLSchema don't get HTML tags

Tags: schema, yui, yui3, yui-datatable, yui-datasource

I'm starting try to upgrade a webapp from YUI2 to YUI3 and get a litle issue when trying to upgrade the datatables, the table data are stored local in HTML table format, looking for tutorials and examples I can upgrade it easy and displayed well but I got a litle problem...

when I get the cell data with the schema i only get the text on that cell but I need the HTML tags like spans or divs in the cell that the Schema didn't load, u know how can retrieve it ? with YUI2 i get it without problems but in YUI3 I dont know to do that :S

in var myTableData the is the rigth HTML code of the table.
maybe trying change the  locator: "td[1]" for other ...

thanks and sorry for my crappy english.

```
fieldDefs[0] = {key: "proyecto", locator: "td[1]", allowHTML:true};
                ...
myDataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceXMLSchema, {
schema: {
    resultListLocator: "tr",
    resultFields: fieldDefs}
});

colDefs[0] = {  key: "proyecto",
    label: "Proyecto",
    allowHTML: true,
    nodeFormatter: function (o) {
    o.cell.set('innerHTML',o.value);
}
...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like DataSchema.XML._getLocationValue prefers textContent over innerHTML.

I'd suggest omitting the DataSchema.XML processor and just subscribe to the DataSource's `data` event and do the value extraction manually.  Either that or use something like this: https://gist.github.com/2023955

The alternative is overriding DataSchema.XML._getLocationValue in your sandbox.  It's a fairly small method after you trim out the comments.

HTH

Comment: Hi luke, thanks for your fast answer, but at the end we'll upgrade the project from YUI2 to YUI3 and load the DataSource from Ajax request.